# .net: send UDP message does not working on Public IP

Tags: .net, wcf, service, udp

I am trying to send UDP message through WCF .net application to Android device, which working fine in LAN(Local Area Network) environment

but When I deploy that WCF service (MyService.svc) to PUblic IP (IIS) it sends UDP packet successfully but deice does not receive that packet.

Code to send UDP message

```
public void SendUDPMessage(IPEndPoint ipeSender, string Message)
{
    byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Message);
    if (serverSocket == null)
       serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    serverSocket.BeginSendTo(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, ((EndPoint)ipeSender), new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null);

}
```

Comment: Have you used a network sniffer like WireShark to verify the packet was actually sent over the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Android device is on a wireless/cellular network, it is effectively behind an NAT firewall and so any network traffic which originates externally will be blocked.

In order to punch through the NAT/firewall, the Android device needs to first send a message to the server.  Then the server must respond to the exact address and port number that are given as the UDP messages' source.

NAT hole punching is a messy subject, which a lot of subtle issues.  But it should work so long as the server has a real public IP address, the mobile device sends the first message, and you aren't doing any of the dozens of other things that can cause a UDP packet to be lost (packet larger than 1400 bytes, first few bytes look like a Teredo tunnel, server using a blocked port, sending data too quickly, server firewall misconfigured, etc.).